# Unity's Mathf.PingPong in Java

Tags: java, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create an implementation of Unity's Mathf.PingPong in java. (Mathf.PingPong reference:  docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html). I have created a simple version so far, but its using the `sin()` function so its slow and smooth.

What I have so far:

```
public float pingpong(float max, float dist) {
  return lerp(0, max, sin(radians((max/dist)*360.0))/2.0+0.5);
}
```

This a) does not work, it fails to ping pong the values and b) returns the values with `sin()`

Note:
Im using a library that adds simplified functions, like sin() and radians()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out myself, and as far as I can tell it works perfectly. Here it is:

```
public float pingpong(float start, float stop, float dist) {
  float d = stop-start;
  if ((int)(Math.abs(dist)/d) % 2 == 0) {
    return start + Math.abs(dist)%d;
  } else {
    return stop - Math.abs(dist)%d;
  }
}
```

I modified it slightly from Unity's version, so it can have an start value. One thing to note is that `dist` is the distance from the `start` (ie. if the start is 5 and your looking for pingponging 8, the dist would be 3). It also works for negative numbers and floats.

Comment: One thing to note is that if `start` and `stop` are the same, it will give a divide by 0 error